# Origin of pronunciation of "I"

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

When I began to study English in my high school (Moscow Institute of Applied Physics) I could not believe our teacher (or tutor?) that the English pronounce it as /aɪ/. I was all of shocked. In school I studied French and I always thought that all normal nations (at least European) pronounce it as /ɪ/. What is the origin of such crazy behavior of Englishmen?

Comment: Saying that people pronounce "I" as "I" is not incredibly helpful. Perhaps find a less ambiguous way to state the pronunciation, or see IPA: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:IPA/Introduction

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the question. Neither Englishmen nor other English-language speakers pronounce "I" as "AI", I don't think. When I see "AI", I think of "Artificial Intelligence". Or Cthulhu "Aiy!".

Comment: The name of the letter is /ay/, just as the name of one letter in the Russian alphabet is /i kratkoye/ or the name of one letter in the Spanish alphabet is /i griego/. The name of a letter is not how it is pronounced.

Comment: > The name of a letter is not how it is pronounced. –        When they pronounce "tide" as "taid"

Comment: Incorrect that "all normal nations (at least European)" pronounce I as /I/; the pronunciation [in German](http://german.about.com/od/pronunciation/a/The-German-Alphabet.htm) is like /iː/.

Comment: @JohnLawler Actually, the Spanish letter you’re  referring to is actually known as [i griega](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y) because all letters are feminine in Spanish. You may be thinking of Portuguese, where that same letter really is [i griego](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y). I wish I knew why the names of the letters are masculine in Portuguese yet are feminine in Spanish.

Comment: @tchrist - Sorry, my mistake. I learned Spanish as an adult in Mexico and still have to look up stuff like gender.

Comment: @RégisRoux -- I don't care if he's a troll. This is an opportunity to answer a question he may be asking, correctly. That's enough.

Comment: Foreign languages always look "crazy". You need to remember that comparison (crazy, normal) is always relative. What looks crazy to you is perfectly normal to other people.

Comment: @tchrist - Actually, in Portuguese, Y is called ypsilon or i grego and not i griego

Comment: Sorry, not crucial to the original question, but just to make sure people are aware: "i" is "i latina" in Spanish, and "y" is "i griega". You can just say "i" for "i latina" if the context is clear, though. But the general point stands: it's all arbitrary.

Comment: @happy_emi, haha... it was on purpose from my side, keeping tongue in cheek

Answer (score 11):

The names of the English vowel letters used to be the same as all European languages:

- **A, E, I, O, U** /*a:, e:, i:, o:, u:*/.

That was before the [Great Vowel Shift](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/GreatVowelShift.pdf), as choster has explained.

Now they have different names, respectively

- **A, E, I, O, U** /*ey, iy, ai, ow, yu*/.

That's because the writing system didn't change, but the pronunciation of the language did.

Answer (score 8):

English underwent a major and very rapid change in pronunciation around the 15th century known as the Great Vowel Shift, which explains in part why its spelling, pronunciation, and even names for letters of the alphabet vary from those of other European languages.

An English professor has posted a site including an audio demonstration of the shift at  http://eweb.furman.edu/~mmenzer/gvs/ . [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) the reason for the shift is unknown, but may be related to changes in society, such as English displacing French as the language of the aristocracy.

Comment: That's the answer but.... > According to Wikipedia the reason for the shift is unknown

Comment: @trg787 Not everything about everything is known yet

Comment: @simchona, try to think logically: the answer is the answer/reason is unknown

Comment: @trg787 Because people aren't perfect? Don't patronize me.

Comment: @simchona,  choster's explanation is enough for me  That's all, nothing above it I put to it.

Comment: It is hardly ever possible to point to an extrinsic cause for language change. It happens, and we can observe the course of a particular historical change, and deduce some general laws about change (eg that some kinds of change are more likely than others). But we can never (or almost never) confidently say "This change will happen", or "This change started because of ...".